# Unable to record script in Jmeter 2.10 using HTTP Script Recorder

Tags: java, testing, web, jmeter

I have tried all the information you have metioned. But it wont work. Still unable to record the script. I need to work only on IE alone.

> Steps I have followed are
>
> 1. Lanched Jemeter;
> 2. Cretae Thread Group;
> 3. HTTP Request Defaults;
> 4. updated server name/IP and port no;
> 5. Added Recording Controller;
> 6. Under Workbench created HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder;
> 7. Updated URL patterns .*.html;
> 8. Added View Result Tree.
> 9. Clicked on Start and install Roor CA certificate;
> 10. Launched my application and moved on some modules;
> 11. Finally I have did not see any script that has been recorded

.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced similar problems. 
Try resetting your browser.(I tried this with firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to set your browser proxy settings to localhost

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Johan B.

Set your proxy settings in the Browser you are using and everything should would as expected.

If not just let us know!

Oh and make sure you are also using the correct port number when you set your proxy settings in the browser...I've forgotten to this more times than I'd like to admit :)

Best of Luck
Phil